# Free Hex Editor that Supports Chinese Characters

Tags: windows-8.1, hex-editor

I am looking for a Hex Editor that supports viewing of Chinese Characters. I am currently translating an application into English. I have found **Super Unicode Editor** which is really great (but is not free)

[image]

I have tried the following, nothing works:

- Be.HexEditor 1.6.0
- wxHexEditor 0.22
- HxD 1.7.7.0
- xvi32 2.55
- HexEdit 4.0

I am on windows 8.1

Comment: Hex-editing the executable is not how software localization is typically done…

Comment: @Wyzard , this is an abandon-ware I am editing. I don't have the source code.

Comment: Might be of interest: [Comparison of hex editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_hex_editors#Features)

Answer (score 0):

[PSPad](http://www.pspad.com) has support for Chinese characters as mentioned in their [forum](http://forum.pspad.com/read.php?5,23565).  It's much more than a hex editor, but it does include that functionality.